# Regression shows high multicollinearity even after a PCA

Tags: regression, pca, multicollinearity

I am comparing men and women using a measure of personality which has 24 variables. I did a oblimin rotated PCA for women and men separately so that they are truly representative of the population and obtained 4 components. I conducted a step wise regression for women in relation to my DV and obtained results with a VIF of 7-9 which is barely below the threshold of 10 but is acceptable. However, while doing the analysis for men, my VIF is off the charts reaching upto 22! The components in the correlation matrix show high correlation ranging from .800 to .900. Researchers have used oblique rotation to extract the principal components for this data before. I included variables which have a loading of .45 and above in the pattern matrix. How do I solve this issue? What could be the reason for this?

Comment: What drove your decision to run a PCA on the measures of personality? Which personality measure are you using? Usually, a survey like that would load onto factors, of which you would use in the regression. And it sounds like your using individual questions from the survey, which would cause significant multicollinearity.

Comment: You should really be using a structural equation model with latent variables rather than PCA if your items are coming from personality scales. Also stepwise regression is widely considered inappropriate in almost all cases.

Comment: I read more about the use of stepwise regression and you are right, there seems to be widespread consensus regarding its drawbacks- even though a number of studies continue to use this method. What analysis would you recommend if I am trying to find the personality of men and women in relatively gender equal countries controlling for age, GDP and the HDI of a country?

Answer (score 1):

You may be getting a multicollinearity issue because of this:

You are structuring your PCA such that all 24 variables are loading onto a few subfactors, however, the scale you are using already has 6 main factors, of which your 24 factors are loading. To clarify, your PCA looks something like this:

```
PCA(creativity, curiosity, judgment, love of learning, perspective, bravery, perseverance, honesty, zest, love, kindness, social intelligence, teamwork, fairness, leadership, forgiveness, humility, prudence, self-regulation,: appreciation of beauty and excellence, gratitude, hope, humor, spirituality[3])
```

Then you are using the factors loaded for your regression. This will cause significant collinearity because each of these 24 subscales is inherently related to each other as designed by the scale.

To mitigate this, I would recommend this approach:

Run a PCA on this individual subscale to their hierarchical factor (e.g., Factor: Subscales)

```
Wisdom and Knowledge: creativity, curiosity, judgment, love of learning, perspective
Courage: bravery, perseverance, honesty, zest
Humanity: love, kindness, social intelligence
Justice: teamwork, fairness, leadership
Temperance: forgiveness, humility, prudence, self-regulation
Transcendence: appreciation of beauty and excellence, gratitude, hope, humor, spirituality[3]
```

So, you will end up having 6 factors for your regression which include Wisdom, Courage, Humanity, Justice, Temperance, and Transcendence.

This should eliminate any multicollinearity.

Comment: The 6 factors or the virtues are loosely based in theory and there are a number of studies that do not make use of them. Also, there continues to be multicollinearity if I use the virtues given by the VIA institute. There are a number of studies that do a PCA before using this measure of personality and do not report such high collinearity.

Comment: I think we need to take a step back and ask what exactly you are trying to achieve. Are you just wanting to compare the differences between sex's based on their answers to this questionnaire? if so then regression is not the best solution. There was a previous suggestion here that you may want to use SEM; I would disagree as the use of that technique requires significant a priori hypothesis in which you would use to build the model

So, exactly what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to find what women and men look like in gender equal countries using the VIA character strength variables. In other words, what is going right for the women and men in countries where women find representation in politics, education, labor force etc. My aim is to not examine the differences between men and women. I want to see the relationship of men and women separately and examine its relationship to the macro index of the global gender gap report (each country is given a score from 0-1, one meaning greater parity). It is not an individual level comparison.

Comment: To achieve this, previously I conducted a pca and manually calculated the scores for each of the components of the PCA and aggregated them for each country. While computing regression in the first step I controlled for GDP, age, and the level of human development of a country and in the second step added the PCA components all together.